# How to better express these React callback statements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  <Textbox
    label="New Item"
    text={this.state.text}
    callback={function(value) {
      this.setState({new_item:value});
    }.bind(this)} />
```

The meat of the callback are the `new_item` and `value`, so can I have a more expressive statement like this?

```
callback=partially_applied_setstate_to_this(new_item, value)
```

I prefer if it were stock JS features (not too disruptive).

Comment: Are you using React.createClass or ES6 classes?

Comment: @WickyNilliams the former, as I use ES5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using `React.createClass` for defining your components, the easiest thing to do would be to define a method on the class, as these get auto-bound to the instance:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({

  render : function() {
    <Textbox
      label="New Item"
      text={this.state.text}
      callback={this.handleNewItem} />
  },

  handleNewItem : function(value) {
    this.setState({new_item:value});
  }

});
```

If you're using ES6 syntax, you could use a fat arrow function which preserve `this` context:

```
<Textbox
  label="New Item"
  text={this.state.text}
  callback={value => this.setState({new_item:value})} />
```

Comment: Aside: it's convention in React to name props which are expected to be functions as `onX` eg. `onChange`, `onSubmit` rather than the generic name `callback` (which is opaque, not conveying why the callback is invoked)

Answer (score 0):

If you find WickyNilliams's answer tedious for ES5, you could take advantage of **currying**. In this example, I have passed curried versions of setField where the name had been already bound.

```
  setField: function(name, value) {
    this.props.onModify(
      this.props.item.set(name, value))
  },

  render: function() {
    return <div style={{border: "1px solid grey"}}>
      <Textbox
        label="item"
        text={this.props.item.get("name")}
        onChange={this.setField.bind(this, "name")} />
      <Textbox
        label="quantity"
        text={this.props.item.get("quantity")}
        onChange={this.setField.bind(this, "quantity")} />
```

---

Currying with `bind` takes a function and returns another function where a parameter has been bound. The first term in `bind` provides `this` in the function, the second provides `a` and so on.

```
function add(a, b) {
  return a+b;
}

addTwo = add.bind(null, 2)
console.log(addTwo(3)
```

http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but this is not currying, this is partial application. Curried functions are partially applied, but partial application is not currying.